# Cordova 5.3.1 Android app ignoring loglevel

Tags: android, cordova, logging

I am in the process of trying to publish my cordova app to the android app store.

I am going through the documentation on what the steps are and it recommends that I remove Log calls.

I assume that I should be able to set the log loglevel to ensure that only errors are logged.

I've added the following to my confix.xml file:

```
<preference name="LogLevel" value="ERROR"/>
```

But calls to `console.debug` are still appearing in the console when I deploy to the emulator and view `adb logcat`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get console to obey the LogLevel preference.

So I ended up wrapping console in a Logger class that can have its logLevel set via JavaScript and will not delegate call to console if they are below the log level.

Seems really silly that I had to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Default `logLevel` is `ERROR` (according to official [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/config.html)), so your setting didn't changed anything.

I think the problem is the way you are building the project.
`cordova build android`, by default, builds the project in debug mode and logs (and other things) are enabled.
You have to build your project in release mode; take a look [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/cordova-cli/index.html) at `cordova build` command options.

Comment: Thanks, but even if I `cordova build --release` and then install using `./adb install ./android-release.apk` it still logs at the debug level.

Comment: Well, that must be a bug, indeed. I made a test with a release signed build on a real device and logcat is still populated.

Comment: So to confirm, you are experiencing the same issue, LogLevel is ignored even when building a release? What version of Cordova are you using?

Comment: Yes. Latest cordova (6.0) & cordova-android 5.0.0 (which is not the latest, 5.1.1, which was released on 2nd of March)

Comment: More than one year later, this issue has been solved?